# c++ state machine generator

Tags: c++, code-generation, state-machine

Are you aware of any opensource state machine c++ code generators (that will work on linux)? Ideally the tool would output all the state machine logic and the stubs. Also it would accept UML or human readable manifest files as input.

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.MSM](http://www.boost.org/libs/msm/)? It has an EDSL meant to mimic UML and has superb runtime performance.

Comment: lex and yacc definitely generate state machines, and g++ : )

Comment: I would suggest [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't support UML.

Comment: @perreal: That was my first thought, too. The question is too broad.

Comment: I found this article quite good on the topic http://security.hsr.ch/mse/projects/2011_Code_Generator_for_UML_State_Machines.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) has a pretty good reputation.

(I have no specific experience with it).

Comment: +1 on Ragel - decent runtime performance with a KISS implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at Yakindu: http://statecharts.org/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Thingml](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/ThingML). It provides a textual syntax (independent from C) for UML-like state-machines. Something like:

```
import "../hardware/bricks/led.thingml"

thing Blink includes LedMsgs, TimerMsgs
{
    required port HW 
    {   
        sends led_toggle, timer_start
        receives timer_timeout
    }

    statechart BlinkImpl init Blinking 
    {    
        state Blinking 
        {    
            on entry HW!timer_start (1000)

            transition -> Blinking 
            event HW?timer_timeout 
            action HW!led_toggle () 
        }
    }
}
```

ThingML can generate C code that can easily be embedded into C++ programs. It can actually generate more than stubs. We can indeed generate fully operationl code. Of course, when it comes to low-level implementation details, we provide a mean to mix ThingML code with C code.

Note that we also target Java and JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You might find my STTCL framework interesting. It's not a generator, but the available (base) classes map very well to UML statechart definitions.
http://makulik.github.com/sttcl/

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've seen that might work for you is StateProto.  But it outputs C# code.

You should check out StateProto and QHSM.  Open source project is here: http://code.google.com/p/gqhsm/

StateProto is open source and the output functions can be modified to output c++ code for you.  But it uses delegates.

I would recommend that you use a data driven design instead.  StateProto will output XML state machines and there is C# code to load the XML and drive the state machine from the data.

You can find plenty of QHSM implementations in c++.  I don't know if any have XML loaders available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the open source QP/C++ state machine framework and the free QM modeling tool (see http://www.state-machine.com). The QP/C++ framework supports hierarchical state machines (UML statecharts) and allows you to execute multiple such state machines concurrently. QP/C++  has been ported to Linux (see http://www.state-machine.com/linux).

Now, regarding the code generator, the free QM modeling tool (see http://www.state-machine.com/qm) allows you to draw state machine diagrams and generate C++ code for the QP/C++ framework. QM itself is cross-platform and runs on Linux, as well as Windows and Mac OS X.